# Catching exception while converting HTTP request data into enum

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a problem while deserialization of HTTP request value into enum with custom `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer` deserializer implementation:

```
public class EnvelopeColorJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<EnvelopeColor> {

    @Override
    public EnvelopeColor deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String val = p.getValueAsString();
        return EnvelopeColor.fromCode(val);
    }
}
```

This is how I convert value into enum:

```
public static EnvelopeColor fromCode(String code) {
    Assert.notNull(code, "code");
    for (EnvelopeColor type : values()) {
        if (code.equals(type.code)) {
            return type;
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Not supported color: " + code);
}
```

Endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity add(@RequestBody EnvelopeDto envelope) {
// some stuff goes here...
}
```

**Question**

Is there some way how to a) check if HTTP request value is valid enum constant value **before** going to deserialization process or b) how to catch exception in `@ControllerAdvice` exception handler? (I would like to avoid throwing custom exception in `fromCode()` method).

Comment: How is your request defined? (Your endpoint)

Comment: @VeselinDavidov addedd

Comment: It depends. In the normal course of your application would you expect unknown colours? If so, you're better off defining an enum constant for that. If not, throwing an exception in the fromCode method is correct, as it is unexpected behaviour.

Comment: share EnvelopeDto details

Answer (score 1):

You can add an exception handler for class `HttpMessageNotReadableException`.
This exception is thrown when Spring is not able to deserialize the payload into the DTO.

```
@ExceptionHandler(org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
protected @ResponseBody handleIncorrectData(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

....

}
```

Moreover you can define a custom `EnumConverter` which will give the exact details to user which are the correct enum values.

```
public class CustomEnumConverter extends EnumConverter {

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
            UnmarshallingContext context) {
        try {
            return super.unmarshal(reader, context);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            String inputValue = reader.getValue();
            Class contextType = context.getRequiredType();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Object[] enumConstants = contextType.getEnumConstants();
            for (Object o : enumConstants) {
                sb.append(o + ",");
            }
            if (sb.length() > 0)
                sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, inputValue,
                    reader.getNodeName(), sb.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

for catch exception in @ControllerAdvice exception handler, try this :

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationExceptionHandler.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class})
    public @ResponseBody Response<Error> handleIllegalArgumentException(Exception e) {
        logger.error("BadRequestException :: ", e);
        return new Response<Error>(new Error("BadRequestException", e.getMessage()));
    }

}
```